# Testhost process exited with error: You must install or update .NET to run this application

Tags: .net, .net-core, msbuild, .net-6.0, .net-3.0

I recently installed '.net 6 (SDK 6.0.302)' on build and deployment environments.
Now these environments have following SDKs installed:

```
2.1.504 
2.1.510 
2.1.511 
2.1.518 
2.1.807 
2.1.810 
2.1.811 
3.1.108 
3.1.302 
3.1.414 
5.0.210 
6.0.302  (default)
```

And following runtimes installed:

```
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.8 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.14 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.15 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.19 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.22 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.23 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.8 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.14 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.15 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.19 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.22 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.23 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.6 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.8 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.20 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.22 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.26 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.13 
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.6 
-Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.8 
-Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.14 
-Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.15 
-Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.19 
-Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.22 
-Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.23 
-Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.6 
-Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.8 
-Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.20 
-Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.22 
-Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.26 
-Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.13 
-Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.6 
-Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.6 
-Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.8 
-Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.20 
-Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.22 
-Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.13 
-Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.6
```

For now all the projects are targeting '.net 3.1' .

And just after the install of '.net 6' , projects are complaining at random during build/test/runtime.

**With following error:**

```
   error Architecture: x64
   error Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.27' (x64)
   error .NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\
   error The following frameworks were found:
   error 2.1.8 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   error 2.1.14 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   error 2.1.15 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   error 2.1.19 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   error 2.1.22 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   error 2.1.23 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   error 3.1.6 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   error 3.1.8 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   error 3.1.20 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   error 3.1.22 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   error 3.1.26 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   error 5.0.13 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   error 6.0.7 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   error Learn about framework resolution:
   error https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
   error To install missing framework, download:
   error https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch? framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=3.1.27&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

error . Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.

Any idea, on how what caused this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am also getting this error. Nothing changed on my machine, my CIs just broke off. Is Microsoft somehow enforcing the use of specific Framework versions? It was working fine with 3.1.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this error message by upgrading my NuGet packages within my solution that still relied on .NetCore 3.1.

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience , i again faced similar issue down the line , and it seems nuget package update is the way to go

Answer (score 5):

in the  `project_name.csproj` file
change the old donet version

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

to the newest one

```
   <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

just replace 5 with 6

it will run efficiently

Answer (score 1):

Below solution is working for me.

Please open Preferences (File - > Settings) -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolset and Build -> .NET Core CLI executable path and select path to x64 dotnet - /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely because you have added the Nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App of version 3.1.27 that isn't compatible with .NET 6 - it literally tells you in that error message you posted:

> error Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.27' (x64)

If I try and add Microsoft.AspNetCore.App into my .NET6 project, the latest stable version that Nuget offers me is 2.2.8.
I'm not 100% sure what version of .NET package v3.1.27 is for, but I'm guessing probably for .NET7 or later.